# Test commands before executing them in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Is there a way to test all commands of my script if all are succeed before executing them and execute them only if all are succeed?

Comment: What does "succeed" mean here?  If it means that it will produce the desired result with the given input, well, you pretty much have to execute it to know, if you just want to know if a command with the given name exists, there may be other options

Comment: The best you can do is validate sequentially as your script executes. You can add `set -xe` under the `#!/bin/bash` to display all commands as they are executed and exit if any nonzero status is returned by any command.

Comment: You can check a little with `bash -n` and https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at least for the most common definition of "succeed," meaning that they all return a zero exit code. Consider a piece of code that checks whether a host is available, whether it's 12 o'clock, or whether Kenny is still alive. That may be true when the check is run, but it may very well be false when the "actual" code runs.

A common way around this is writing **tests:** create a standalone environment with the appropriate state where you can do whatever you like without destroying important stuff, and run your script there. If it seems to do the right thing on every run, you can have at least some confidence that it will do the right thing in your production environment.

Comment: Note that all the failures are related to side effects, which languages like Haskell go to great lengths to separate from the "pure" code which you *can* reason about without actually executing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The only way to know<sup>1</sup> if a command has failed is to examine the return code; e.g. the value of `$?`.  But you can only get the return code from a program after it has run.

What I think you are trying to do is to "transactionalize" a sequence of Linux commands.  It is not possible because Linux is not transactional.

---

<sup>1 - And even that is not entirely reliable.  A buggy program may not set the exit status correctly.  A program may think that it has succeeded, but may produce incorrect reslts.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `set -x` after shebang in your script. It will provide you details command by command in your code either they are successful or not.

For example following is a script.

```
cat script.ksh
#!/bin/bash
set -x

echo "Hola!!"
find -type f -iname "*.txt"
echoi "Done.."
echo "Done again.."
```

Since system is not able to find `echoi` command so it has given me following error.

```
./script.ksh: line 6: echoi: command not found
```

`set -e` makes the script stop immediately if any external program returns a non-zero exit status. This is useful if your script attempts to handle all error cases and where a failure to do so should be trapped.

Following error will come for above script when use `set -ex`.

```
+ echoi Done..
./script.ksh: line 6: echoi: command not found
```

Comment: That is true, but before that happend. These lines were executed:
echo "Hola!!"
find -type f -iname "*.txt"

I would like to not execute anything if one of commands fail (then I dont want to execute even correct commands). I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @Superman, ok cool, then you should be using `set -e` option see my edit now and let me know if this helps you?